# Why can't I use multer twice in the same route? (Nodejs/Express)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, multer

### The problem

I'm working on a file upload feature in a Nodejs API using express. I'm trying to prevent a file from being uploaded to my AWS S3 bucket if it exceeds a certain size limit.

I know that you can do this using multer's limit property in its config object:

```
limits: { fileSize: mbToBytes(sizeLimit) }
```

The issue is that the file is uploaded to S3 up to the limited amount before throwing the *File Too Large* error, for example, if my limit is 6mb and a 40mb file is uploaded, only the first 6mb would be uploaded to my bucket and that's what I want to prevent.

### What I've tried

Using Multer to store the file in memory and check if it exceeds the limit during that upload, in that case, throw an error and stop the process. Otherwise, continue and call multer again to upload the file to S3.

```
  // ROUTE

    router.post(
      '/upload-cover',
      userController.checkCoverSize,
      userController.uploadCover,
      userController.updateUserCover
    );


    // CONTROLLER

const {
  s3CoverMulterConfig,
  memoryProfileImgMulterConfig
} = require('../utils/awsMulterConfig');

        // Upload cover picture to S3
        const coverUploader = new Uploader(s3CoverMulterConfig, 'cover');
        exports.uploadCover = coverUploader.startUpload.bind(coverUploader);
        
        // Upload cover picture to memory
        const coverMemoryUploader = new Uploader(memoryProfileImgMulterConfig, 'cover');
        exports.checkCoverSize = coverMemoryUploader.startUpload.bind(
          coverMemoryUploader
        );
```

Uploader is a class because I'll be uploading different types of images:

```
// uploader.js

const util = require('util');
const multer = require('multer');
const AppError = require('./appError');
    
class Uploader {
  constructor(options, fileName) {
    this.options = options;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.upload = multer(options);
  }

  async startUpload(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const upload = util.promisify(this.upload.single(this.fileName));
      await upload(req, res);
    } catch (err) {
      return next(new AppError(err));
    }

    return next();
  }
}
```

I also have a file where I export my multer configuration objects:

```
     // awsMulterConfig.js
        
        const aws = require('aws-sdk');
        const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
        const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
        const multer = require('multer');
            
        const s3 = new aws.S3();
         const mbToBytes = (numberInMb) => numberInMb * 1024 * 1024;
        
        aws.config.update({
          secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
          accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY_ID,
          region: process.env.REGION
        });
        
        // Validate the file type
        const fileFilter = (validMimeTypes, errMsg) => (req, file, cb) => {
          if (!validMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
            cb(new Error(errMsg), false);
          }
          cb(null, true);
        };
            
                const generateMulterConfigS3 = (sizeLimit, folderName) => {
                  return {
                    limits: { fileSize: mbToBytes(sizeLimit) },
                    storage: multerS3({
                      acl: 'public-read',
                      s3,
                      bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
                      metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
                        return cb(null, { fieldName: 'TEST_STATIC' });
                      },
                      key: (req, file, cb) => {
                        const fileName = `${folderName}/${nanoid(15)}.${
                          file.mimetype.split('/')[1]
                        }`;
                
                        return cb(null, fileName);
                      },
                      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE 
                    })
                  };
                };
                
                const generateMulterConfigMemory = (validMimeTypes, errMsg, sizeLimit) => {
                  return {
                    fileFilter: fileFilter(validMimeTypes, errMsg),
                    limits: { fileSize: mbToBytes(sizeLimit) },
                    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
                  };
                };

exports.s3CoverMulterConfig = generateMulterConfigS3(2, 'cover');
exports.memoryProfileImgMulterConfig = generateMulterConfigMemory(
  ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'],
  'Your image must be .jpeg/jpg or .png!',
  2
);
```

### Behavior of the problem

The first function runs correctly and puts the file in memory, the second one runs but doesn't upload the file to S3 and hence it doesn't update req.file. If I remove the first one, the second one correctly uploads the file to S3, it's like you can't parse multipart form data with Multer twice in the same route.

```
   // ROUTE

    router.post(
      '/upload-cover',
      userController.checkCoverSize,
      userController.uploadCover,
      userController.updateUserCover
    );
```

### Behavior I was expecting

The second function should upload the file to S3 and rewrite the content of req.file.
I've verified that `checkImgSize` is able to throw an error if the file is larger than the limit.

### Client I'm using to make the requests

Postman v7.34.0.
Content-Type header is set to *multipart/form-data; boundary= < calculated when request is sent >*

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can't use multer twice on the same request because once the data has been read from the incoming read stream, it's gone unless you put it somewhere else (like in the file system).  So, you could download the file to your file system before you start uploading it somewhere and if it does not exceed the file limit, then you could start uploading to S3.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you, I solved this by uploading the file to memory with multer and then uploading that buffer to my bucket through s3.putObject's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `multer` twice on the same request because once the data has been read from the incoming read stream, it's gone unless you put it somewhere else (like in the file system). Instead, you have several options:

1. You can let it be uploaded to S3 until it exceeds the size limit and then stop the uploading and then delete that item from S3.
2. You can download the file to your file system and when it has successfully finished and does not exceed the file size limit, you can then start uploading it to S3.  If it does exceed the limit, then you must remove the partial download from the file system.
3. You can download the file to memory and when it has successfully finished and does not exceed the file size limit, you can then start uploading it to S3.  If it does exceed the limit, then you must remove the partial download from memory.

Options #2 and #3 save bandwidth to S3 (if that's an expense that matters) for the cases where the file size was exceeded, but option #1 will likely get the normal upload to S3 faster.